# Combine the results of Exercises 45 and 47 into a single “if and only if” theorem.

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

From Gallian's "Contemporary Abstract Algebra", Chapter 6.

Question 45:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $g \in G$. If $z \in Z(G)$, show that the inner
> automorphism induced by $g$ is the same as the inner automorphism
> induced by $zg$ (that is, that the mappings $\phi_g$
> and $\phi_{zg}$ are equal).

Question 47:

> Suppose that $g$ and $h$ induce the same inner automorphism of a
> group $G$. Prove that $h^{-1}g \in Z(G)$

Let $g, h \in G$.

Then if $h^{-1}g \in Z(G)$ then $\phi_g =
\phi_{h^{-1}gg} = \phi_{gh^{-1}g}$ by Exercise 45.

Conversely, if $\phi_g = \phi_{gh^{-1}g}$  then $(gh^{-1}g)^{-1}g = g^{-1}h$ is in $Z(G)$ by Exercise 47, and so its inverse $h^{-1}g$.

Is that it?

Comment: I think you could phrase it a little more compactly: "Two elements $g,h \in G$ induce the same automorphism if and only if $h^{-1}g \in Z(G)$" would be my idea of what was wanted here. The "only if" part is precisely Question 47 and the "if" part follows from Question 45 (if $h^{-1}g \in Z(G)$, then $h$ and $h(h^{-1}g) = g$ induce the same automorphism)

Comment: That could be an answer, @Lukas.